# Subspace $\operatorname{null}(T^2+bT+c)^j$ has even dimension when $b^2<4c$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Question:** Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space and $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Let $b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $b^2<4c$. Prove that for every $j$, $\operatorname{null}(T^2+bT+c)^j$ has even dimension.

What I have done is,

If $W=\operatorname{null}(T^2+bT+c)^j$ then $T$ restricted on $W$ has the annihilating polynomial $(x^2+bx+c)^j$. Now $b^2-4c<0$ and $V$ is real vector space so $x^2+bx+c$ can not be factored. So minimal polynomial of $T|_W$ has minimal polynomial of the form $(x^2+bx+c)^k$, where $k\leq j$.

After that I have no idea what to do. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every linear operator acting on an odd dimensional vector space has an eigenvalue, so if $W$ is odd dimensional, $T|_W$ has an eigenvalue. But this eigenvalue must necessarily be a root of the minimal polynomial. This is a contradiction, since $(x^2 + bx + c)^k$ is not divisible by a linear factor.

Comment: Very nice. But I am having a doubt that, this proof is done if somehow $W$ is finite dimensional, but here how can you garantee that?

Comment: If $V$ is finite dimensional, then $W$ is trivially finite dimensional as a subspace of $V$. If $V$ is infinite dimensional, then I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: @AVISEKSHARMA $W$ can be infinite-dimensional. However, if it isn't *supposed* to be finite-dimensional, what do you mean by showing that it has an even dimension?

Comment: I don't know, probably then the question should be corrected. I thought firstly we have to prove $W$ is finite dimensional and then it is even.